# Using HTTrack download a specific directory on a PHP website

Tags: download, website, httrack

I need to copy PHP/HTML files from:

```
https://example.com/file.php?page=1
https://example.com/file.php?page=2
https://example.com/file.php?page=3
https://example.com/file.php?page=4
…
```

I used this in in HTTrack. But it download no files:

```
-*
+https://example.com/file.php?page=*
-mime:*/* +mime:text/html
```

Can you give a correct method to do this?

Comment: The website you are targeting might disallow direct downloads or even block crawlers.

Comment: I can copy that website if I dont use any sorting rules

Answer (score 0):

The page ID indicates that something is being dynamically generated on each page based on a number.  The wildcard won't work.  You'd have to either iterate though the numbers or specify the page ID's manually.